# Controlling ggplot x-axis ticks that are dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have some code that downloads covid data and produces a chart.  The data is aggregated by weeks and I;ve been working on making it dynamically shift the window based on the most current data.  With help from this site I've got the `lubridate` function `floor_date` handling that for me.

```
weekday=wday(max(MAdata$Date))
MAcum <- round((sum(MAdata$totalTestResultsIncrease)/MApop) * 100,1)
MAWeekly <- MAdata %>% mutate(weekStarting=floor_date(Date, "week", week_start=weekday)) %>%
  group_by(weekStarting) %>%
  summarise(posInc = sum(positiveIncrease, na.rm=TRUE), 
            totInc=sum(totalTestResultsIncrease, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(posRate = (posInc/totInc)*100, 
         dailyTest = (totInc/MApop$TotalPop)*100,
         state=paste("MA ",MAcum,"%",sep=""))
```

So ultimately I wind up with data this is grouped by weeks that may run Wednesday to the following Tuesday if that encompasses the latest data.  But when I plot it, ggplot makes the x-axis tick marks Mondays, always.  And obviously that doesn't line up with my data.  So I get a chart that looks like

[image]

when I would ideally like the dates in the tick marks to be the dates that center on the columns.  How can I accomplish this?

For reproducibility, this script uses a big dput to alleviate the downloading and manipulating the data

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(dplyr)    
library(tidyr)    
library(stringr)  
library(gtable)
library(cowplot)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyquant)
library(lubridate)

stateWeekly <- structure(list(weekStarting = structure(c(18354, 18361, 18368, 
18375, 18382, 18389, 18396, 18354, 18361, 18368, 18375, 18382, 
18389, 18396, 18354, 18361, 18368, 18375, 18382, 18389, 18396, 
18354, 18361, 18368, 18375, 18382, 18389, 18396, 18354, 18361, 
18368, 18375, 18382, 18389, 18396, 18354, 18361, 18368, 18375, 
18382, 18389, 18396, 18354, 18361, 18368, 18375, 18382, 18389, 
18396, 18354, 18361, 18368, 18375, 18382, 18389, 18396, 18354, 
18361, 18368, 18375, 18382, 18389, 18396), class = "Date"), posInc = c(479L, 
613L, 665L, 902L, 1164L, 1074L, 980L, 1679L, 1717L, 1763L, 2524L, 
3572L, 2432L, 2162L, 8802L, 7467L, 10972L, 11104L, 12315L, 12326L, 
12916L, 5263L, 5086L, 5753L, 4832L, 5124L, 4636L, 4315L, 805L, 
739L, 631L, 579L, 728L, 651L, 680L, 834L, 696L, 903L, 1050L, 
1100L, 1025L, 1090L, 2601L, 2643L, 6326L, 3186L, 4273L, 4145L, 
3715L, 8500L, 7056L, 5798L, 4884L, 4809L, 4400L, 5069L, 9053L, 
13278L, 14943L, 15352L, 11760L, 8472L, 8473L), totInc = c(9005L, 
10605L, 8027L, 20868L, 21506L, 27038L, 31957L, 24166L, 24278L, 
34084L, 53569L, 58552L, 65816L, 61096L, 114337L, 72222L, 248841L, 
137812L, 205897L, 256556L, 314528L, 18461L, 25303L, 29982L, 49867L, 
60198L, 69767L, 129036L, 11378L, 15874L, 16694L, 15354L, 21623L, 
26237L, 35244L, 14949L, 11498L, 28846L, 29318L, 25224L, 25784L, 
22878L, 23802L, 18211L, 26954L, 30402L, 40021L, 56925L, 63674L, 
76650L, 70375L, 75118L, 84861L, 106563L, 114712L, 176585L, 35777L, 
45219L, 56942L, 75916L, 74021L, 70393L, 79921L), posRate = c(5.31926707384786, 
5.78029231494578, 8.28453967858478, 4.32240751389688, 5.41244303915186, 
3.97218729195946, 3.06662077166192, 6.94777786973434, 7.07224647829311, 
5.17251496303251, 4.71168026283858, 6.10056018581774, 3.69515011547344, 
3.53869320413775, 7.69829538994376, 10.338954889092, 4.40924124239977, 
8.05735349606711, 5.98114591276221, 4.8044091738256, 4.10647064808221, 
28.5087481718217, 20.1003833537525, 19.1881795744113, 9.68977480097058, 
8.51191069470747, 6.64497541817765, 3.34402802318733, 7.07505712779047, 
4.6554113644954, 3.77980112615311, 3.77100429855412, 3.36678536743283, 
2.48122879902428, 1.92940642378845, 5.57896849287578, 6.05322664811272, 
3.13041669555571, 3.58141755917866, 4.36092610212496, 3.97533354017996, 
4.7644024827345, 10.9276531383917, 14.5132063038823, 23.4696148994583, 
10.4795737122558, 10.6768946303191, 7.28151075977163, 5.83440650815089, 
11.0893672537508, 10.0262877442274, 7.71852285737107, 5.75529395128504, 
4.51282340024211, 3.83569286561127, 2.87057224566073, 25.3039662352908, 
29.3637630199695, 26.2424923606477, 20.2223510195479, 15.8873833101417, 
12.0352875996193, 10.6017191977077), dailyTest = c(0.214729002698837, 
0.25288185159591, 0.191408073810501, 0.49760853174007, 0.512821980237778, 
0.644735455299407, 0.762031620127345, 0.176932085783727, 0.177752097105741, 
0.249547016959884, 0.392207022401245, 0.428690204701184, 0.481873796157486, 
0.447316176158347, 0.144685607792809, 0.0913919725549231, 0.314891166715677, 
0.174391605352096, 0.260548489008072, 0.324653968469453, 0.398013546339825, 
0.086937291657307, 0.119157916191151, 0.141192453196976, 0.234835703541245, 
0.283486868706276, 0.328549592495279, 0.607661576636817, 0.143771586903215, 
0.200582718448025, 0.210944179272479, 0.194012035973981, 0.273226667569714, 
0.331528838599019, 0.445340640606161, 0.233144039940636, 0.179322374154621, 
0.449881127575595, 0.457242421765974, 0.393392552241795, 0.402126291111736, 
0.356804424761647, 0.101812799958936, 0.0778973573671198, 0.115295446184907, 
0.130044229239206, 0.171189398670556, 0.243496077542326, 0.272364852726044, 
0.178440587106547, 0.163832437281451, 0.17487410335642, 0.197555729451385, 
0.248077811922178, 0.267048618762768, 0.411088468026217, 0.259535614275395, 
0.328030325122818, 0.413072000113747, 0.55071430509352, 0.536967484816474, 
0.510649034175248, 0.579767611272712), state = c("NM 3.4%", "NM 3.4%", 
"NM 3.4%", "NM 3.4%", "NM 3.4%", "NM 3.4%", "NM 3.4%", "TN 2.6%", 
"TN 2.6%", "TN 2.6%", "TN 2.6%", "TN 2.6%", "TN 2.6%", "TN 2.6%", 
"CA 1.7%", "CA 1.7%", "CA 1.7%", "CA 1.7%", "CA 1.7%", "CA 1.7%", 
"CA 1.7%", "GA 1.9%", "GA 1.9%", "GA 1.9%", "GA 1.9%", "GA 1.9%", 
"GA 1.9%", "GA 1.9%", "OK 1.8%", "OK 1.8%", "OK 1.8%", "OK 1.8%", 
"OK 1.8%", "OK 1.8%", "OK 1.8%", "UT 2.8%", "UT 2.8%", "UT 2.8%", 
"UT 2.8%", "UT 2.8%", "UT 2.8%", "UT 2.8%", "OH 1.2%", "OH 1.2%", 
"OH 1.2%", "OH 1.2%", "OH 1.2%", "OH 1.2%", "OH 1.2%", "FL 1.8%", 
"FL 1.8%", "FL 1.8%", "FL 1.8%", "FL 1.8%", "FL 1.8%", "FL 1.8%", 
"MA 3.6%", "MA 3.6%", "MA 3.6%", "MA 3.6%", "MA 3.6%", "MA 3.6%", 
"MA 3.6%")), row.names = c(NA, -63L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

g <- stateWeekly %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(weekStarting))) +
  geom_col(aes(y=100*dailyTest), size=0.75, color="darkblue", fill="white") +
  geom_line(aes(y=posRate), size = 0.75, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Test Positivity Rate", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name="Percent of Pop Tested")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 week', date_labels = "%b %d") +
    labs(x = "Week Starting",
       title = "COVID-19 Testing",
       #subtitle = paste("Data as of", format(max(as.Date(COVtests$date)), "%A, %B %e, %y")),
       caption = "HQ AFMC/A9A \n Data: The COVID Tracking Project (https://covidtracking.com)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color='red'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1),
        strip.background =element_rect(fill="white"),
        strip.text = element_text(colour = 'blue')) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,75)) +
  facet_wrap(~ state)


print(g)
```

Comment: `scale_x_date(breaks=...)` can be a function, where given a range you control the breaks programmatically. Combine that with `lubridate::` functions and you can change it from always using Mondays.

Comment: `object 'COVtests' not found`, though commenting out the subtitle for this question seems reasonable.

Comment: My bad...overlooked that when copying.  Commented out now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scale_x_date(breaks=)` argument can take a function, with which you can programmatically control the labels.

**Edit**: the use of "4" is hard-coded for *my* locale; I don't know what other locales may return for Wednesday, so it might be useful to replace `4` below with `lubridate::wday("2020-05-20")` (since today is Wednesday).

```r
my_dates <- function(d) {
  seq( d[1] + (4 - wday(d[1])) %% 7, d[2] + 6, by = "week")
}

# ...
  scale_x_date(breaks = my_dates, date_labels = "%b %d") +
#...
```

[image: ggplot2, with date ticks shifted to Wednesdays]

Updated code (sans `subtitle=`, since we lack `COVtests`):

```r
g <- stateWeekly %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(weekStarting))) +
  geom_col(aes(y=100*dailyTest), size=0.75, color="darkblue", fill="white") +
  geom_line(aes(y=posRate), size = 0.75, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Test Positivity Rate", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name="Percent of Pop Tested")) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = my_dates, date_labels = "%b %d") +
    labs(x = "Week Starting",
       title = "COVID-19 Testing",
       # subtitle = paste("Data as of", format(max(as.Date(COVtests$date)), "%A, %B %e, %y")),
       caption = "HQ AFMC/A9A \n Data: The COVID Tracking Project (https://covidtracking.com)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color='red'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1),
        strip.background =element_rect(fill="white"),
        strip.text = element_text(colour = 'blue')) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,75)) +
  facet_wrap(~ state)
```

Comment: trying to follow that...the hard coded `4` in the my_date function is for the specific instance of weeks that go Wed-Tues, correct?  I could replace that 4 with a call to wday() to make this dynamic?  I'll play around but figured I'd ask in case I'm way off...

Comment: The `4` is because `wday` (on my system) reports Wednesdays as 4. Yes, you can omit the hard-coded 4 by using a date you "know" is Wednesday and storing that as your offset. (Come to think of it, that might be a locale-sensitive number, so yes you should probably do it programmatically.)

Comment: Thanks! Wound up with
 ```maxDate <- max(as.Date(as.character(COVtests$date),format="%Y%m%d"))
```
```my_dates <- function(d) {
  seq( d[1] + (wday(maxDate) - wday(d[1])+1) %% 7, d[2] + 6, by = "week")
}
```
and it works great